# tilted slippers?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, phrasal-verbs

```
They painted their lips and theirnails, they darkened their lashes and lightened their hair, and scent seemed to shimmer fromthem. They wore thin, bright dresses, tight aver their breasts and high on their legs, *and tilted slippers, fancifully strapped*. They looked proud and cheap and charming
```

I'll need to ask another question from this text because I'm having really hard time to understand Mrs. Parker's idiomatic language.
What does this text mean by "fancifully strapped tilted slippers" like... what kind of shoe are we talking about in this context?

Comment: I assume it must refer to high-heeled shoes with fancy straps. (Light-weight dancing shoes used to be called 'slippers'.)

Comment: Oh I've never thought about that one, thanks. Then what does "fancifully" refer to in this context because I get the feeling like after the author describes them as "cheap-looking" I assumed it'd mean something negative like "weirdly strapped high-heeled shoes" or am I reading too much into it?

Comment: As I said, the shoes presumably have fancy (decorative) straps.

Comment: Okay then I'll take it as literally. Thanks for the help :)